# SQL query: Simulating an "AND" over several rows instead of sub-querying

Tags: sql, join

Suppose I have a "tags" table with two columns: **tagid** and **contentid**.  Each row represents a tag assigned to a piece of content.  I want a query that will give me the contentid of every piece of content which is tagged with tagids 334, 338, and 342.

The "easy" way to do this would be (*pseudocode*):

```
select contentid from tags where tagid = 334 and contentid in (
    select contentid from tags where tagid = 338 and contentid in (
        select contentid from tags where tagid = 342
    )
)
```

However, my gut tells me that there's a better, faster, more extensible way to do this.  For example, what if I needed to find the intersection of 12 tags?  This could quickly get horrendous.  Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Turns out that this is also covered in [this excellent blog post](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/jeffs/archive/2007/06/12/60230.aspx).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
SELECT contentID
FROM tags
WHERE tagID in (334, 338, 342)
GROUP BY contentID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tagID) = 3


--In general
SELECT contentID
FROM tags
WHERE tagID in (...) --taglist
GROUP BY contentID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tagID) = ... --tagcount
```

Comment: That's it. Although if tagid, contentid is unique, then perhaps DISTINCT is not needed in COUNT(DISTINCT tagID)

Comment: Very smart solution but it would need a tweak  on our installation of SQL2000.  We can't use "having" without having an aggregation in the select clause.  Easy enough to work around though.

Comment: I only know t-sql Max, maybe someone else knows about other sql flavors?

Comment: I haven't tested this in other DBs, but all of the commands used are part of the SQL standard, so they *should* work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that has worked much faster than the for me on a very large database of objects and tags. This is an example for a three-tag intersection. It just chains many joins on the object-tag table (`objtags`) to indicate the same object and stipulates the tag IDs in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT w0.objid

FROM       objtags t0
INNER JOIN objtags t1 ON t1.objid=t0.objid
INNER JOIN objtags t2 ON t2.objid=t1.objid

WHERE t0.tagid=512
  AND t1.tagid=256
  AND t2.tagid=128
```

I have no idea why this runs faster. It was inspired by the search code in the MusicBrainz server. Doing this in Postgres, I usually get a ~8-10x speedup over the `HAVING COUNT(...)` solution.

Comment: You're using set intersection instead of aggregation to determine whether all three values apply. Less thrashing. That's gorgeous, I wish I'd thought of it.

Answer (score 1):

The only alternative way i can think of is:

```
select a.contentid from tags a
inner join tags b on a.contentid = b.contentid and b.tagid=334
inner join tags c on a.contentid = c.contentid and c.tagid=342
where a.tagid=338
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is better but it might be more maintainable

```
select contentid from tags where tagid = 334
intersect
select contentid from tags where tagid = 338
intersect
select contentid from tags where tagid = 342
```

You'd have to build it dynamically which wouldn't be as bad as your original solution.

Answer (score -1):

What type of SQL? MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?

In SQL Server doesn't this equate to:

```
select contentid from tags where tagid IN (334,338,342)
```

Comment: No, that would give you all the articles in the 3 tags, he wants all the articles which have the same 3 tags