# Select items by tag when searching multiple tags

Tags: .net, linq

I'm struggling a bit here so I thought why not ask:

Every entity in my system has a list of tags (a list of strings), and I want to be able to search for multiple tags at once.

I have a IQueryable to work with. Every Entity has a IList called Tags and my input parameter is a IList.

I simply could go through all tags and do IQueryable.Where(p => p.Tags.Contains(currentTag), but that would not scale very well with many tags as input, and also I have the feeling that this could be done inside LinQ.

Hope anyone has an Idea.

Edit: Clarification of question:
I search for a way to only select Items from my IQueryable that contain ALL supplied parameter tags (of IList).

greetings Daniel / Tigraine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163887/sql-query-simulating-an-and-over-several-rows-instead-of-sub-querying#163907), this is some sql that will work for you:

```
SELECT entityID
FROM tags
WHERE tagID in (...) --taglist
GROUP BY entityID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tagID) = ... --tagcount
```

Now the trick is getting Linq to produce it...  Here's some LinqToSql code:

```
public List<int> GetEntityIds(List<int> tagIds)
{
  int tagCount = tagIds.Count;

  CustomDataContext myDC = new CustomDataContext();

  List<int> entityIds = myDC.Tags
    .Where(t => tagIds.Contains(t.TagId))
    .GroupBy(t => t.entityId)
    .Where(g => g.Select(t => t.TagId).Distinct().Count() == tagCount)
    .Select(g => g.Key)

  return entityIds;
}
```

A few caveats apply:

- List(T).Contains is translated by LinqToSql, but LinqToEntities will not translate it.  You will instead get a runtime exception.
- IList.Contains... nobody translates that.  Use List(T) instead.
- There is a parameter count limit in effect for sql server.  It's approximately 2000 parameters (higher, but lower than 2500).  If you need to use more than 2000 tags, you should seek a different solution.
- I wrote this without tools, after midnight.  It's probably not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I really understand what you're asking, but maybe something like the following would work.

```
List<string> searchTags = ...

var query = db.MyEntity
              .Where( e => e.Tags.Intersect( searchTags ).Count() > 0 );
```

This should give you the set of entities where the list of tags contains at least one of the items in `searchTags`

Comment: I just added a clarification to the answer and will try.. I thought about the Intersecct,.. but didn't follow up there.