# Find foreign key matching multiple row values using linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a table called conversation that lists the users who are in the same conversation. Eg:

```
id | conversation | user
1  |  1           |  Bob
2  |  1           |  Jane
3  |  2           |  Tim
4  |  2           |  Lily
5  |  2           |  Rick
```

And I have list has some users like so..

```
List<string> usernames = new List<string>{"Bob","Jane"};
```

I now want to check when a user wants to start a conversation with other users whether they have previously had a conversation with those other users (exclusively).

Eg. Bob wants to create a new conversation with Jane.(I have Bob and Jane in my username List values to compare  if those have been in conversation before?)

As we see they two have a conversation already, I want to get the conversation id belong these two guys.

if my list contains following data like so..

```
List<string> usernames = new List<string>{"Bob","Jane","Tim"};
```

This time I am expecting there is no conversation those 3 before.

I want to find out there is no conversation i can create one new for them.

I have trying this with Linq but cannot get any correct result so far.

Thank in advance for your help;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the SequenceEqual method to compare 2 sequences.

```
var users1 = new List<String> { "Bob", "Jane" };
var users2 = new List<String> { "Bob", "Jane", "Tim" };
var tableData = new List<YourTable>
    {
        new YourTable {foreignKey = 1, name = "Bob"},
        new YourTable {foreignKey = 1, name = "Jane"},
        new YourTable {foreignKey = 2, name = "Tim"},
        new YourTable {foreignKey = 2, name = "Lily"},
        new YourTable {foreignKey = 2, name = "Rick"},
    };
var keyFound = (from t in tableData
                group t by t.foreignKey into users
                where users.Select(u => u.name).SequenceEqual(users1)
                select users.Key).FirstOrDefault();

var keyNull = (from t in tableData
               group t by t.foreignKey into users
               where users.Select(u => u.name).SequenceEqual(users2)
               select users.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

Edit:
You're using linq as a means to fetch data from the database, not all operations are supported this way. What we can do is extract the selection in memory and then we can use all operations again.
Depending on your situation this might not be a good idea, usually you want to let sql handle all the query power since he is better at that.
But if you are selecting on a not so big table you can easily pull in memory feel free to do it like this :

```
var rawData = (from t in tableData
               group t by t.foreignKey into users
               select users).ToList();

var key = (from d in rawData
           where d.Select(u => u.name).SequenceEqual(users2)
           select d.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

If on the other hand the data is too big and you want it executed on sql side i would consider make a stored procedure for this.

Comment: Thanks @Kristof for the quick reply. I have tried this code but some reason it throw an exception says "Sequence contains no elements. basically it wont support some reason SequenceEqual methot. I dont know why?. Thanks again.

Comment: Try breaking it up to find out where the no element exception is coming from. Are you using this code to the letter and did you create your own YourTable class or did you modify it? You could break it up by first grouping it and then iterate over all the groups. Debugging would also work if you keep pressing f11 :)

Comment: and while debugging, which sequence contains no elements? if your users1 or users2 list is empty then the sequenceEqual will fail. Since you are grouping the only reason why the other list would be empty might be that your name column is null for some records. Try to give me some more insight please :)

Comment: I m trying use my own table. sorry for typing wrong error message before. I just find out after send the my comment. The error message is throwing actually is "The query operator 'SequenceEqual' is not supported.", When I search that someone recommend using the folowing way. ".AsEnumerable().SequenceEqual". but it didnt do the trick. Thanks @Kristof for the answer. I am really appreciated .

Comment: Hi Kristof, Thanks for your effort and help. I think with the row data I cannot get key result at all. result always shown 0. Still trying the find solution. Thanks again.

Comment: While debugging you can step to the var key = line. The rawData will contain your sql table grouped by foreign keyID. You'll have to see in there whether or not there is a group that matches your user group(prolly not) and i'm hoping it will become clear what the issue is :)

Comment: I did what you said about debugging and I got some result but It is not exactly giving the result what I wanted.  For example, I have conversation id 1 and users associated with this id : Bob, Jane as in my post above. I have "List<string> usernames = new List<string>{"Bob","Jane"};". when I compare with this list I get the right result but if I swap the names in the list like so "List<string> usernames = new List<string>{"Jane","Bob"};. This time no result because index number not match. Hopefully my explanation is enough clear @Kristof :) Thanks for your help and I m really appreciated.

Comment: Could you maybe post the code you currently have? You should select only the usersnames and compare this to your string array. The index should not be compared. Like this : users.Select(u => u.name).SequenceEqual(usernames)

Comment: Thanks again Kristof. I used the code u have provided and add the orderby clouse to it then it did the trick work. Huge thanks for your help and effort.

Comment: Thanks Kristof I did it.

Answer (score 2):

You can group by conversation IDs and match the groups with your list of users:

```
var previousConversations = userConversations
    .GroupBy(uc => uc.Conversation)
    .Where(g => g.OrderBy(uc => uc.user).Select(uc => uc.user)
        .SequenceEqual(usernames.Sort()));
```

Comment: Thanks @Rob for the quick reply. I have tested this code and give me a close result but not exactly what i wanted. For example if i try to compare " List<string> usernames = new List<string>{"Lily","Tim"}; it still gives me a id 2. there is no conversation between Tim and Lily actually. Is that any way to get this result as i describe. Thanks again..

Comment: My mistake -- I can see why that happened: the first filter made the three-way conversation look like a two-way conversation.  I'll edit my response.

Comment: Hi Rob. Still trying to find out the correct result. I have tried the code you have provided but it doesnt work. I get error saying "The query operator 'SequenceEqual' is not supported." Thanks for your help and effort. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Rob for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically doing a "these tags" query, which is answered over here:

[Select items by tag when searching multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467077/select-items-by-tag-when-searching-multiple-tags/468142#468142)

Applied to your problem, it looks like:

```
int userCount = myUsers.Count;

List<int> conversationIds = conversationsUsers
  .Where(cu => myUsers.Contains(cu.UserName))
  .GroupBy(cu => cu.ConversationId)
  .Where(g => g.Select(cu => cu.Username).Distinct().Count() == userCount)
  .Select(g => g.Key)
```

---

> (exclusively).

Well, ok...  Move the user filtering into the group filtering.

```
int userCount = myUsers.Count;

List<int> conversationIds = conversationsUsers
  .GroupBy(cu => cu.ConversationId)
  .Where(g => g.Select(cu => cu.Username).Distinct().Count() == userCount)
  .Where(g => g.Select(cu => cu.UserName).All(userName => myUsers.Contains(userName)))
  .Select(g => g.Key)
```

Comment: So the match on Distinct().Count() gives you two-way containment.  I like it.

Comment: Hi @David, Thanks for your help and effort. second code you provide gives an error in select section. It says "bool does not contains a definition for select". How can I over come this please? Thanks again.

Comment: @David both codes you have provided is works fine now but not exactly return result what I exactly wanted. For example if i try to compare " List<string> usernames = new List<string>{"Lily","Tim"}; it still gives me a id 2. there is no conversation between Tim and Lily tho but There is one conversation among Tim,Lily and Rick. Any other way that I can achieve this? Thanks again David.

Comment: @Mustapha I didn't properly close the second Where.  editted.  The second query should not give you conversation (Lily, Tim, Rick) if you are asking for (Lily, Tim).  That is what exclusively means.

Comment: Thanks David for your help and effort again.

Answer (score 0):

Check with the following linq. It will result in conversation id if any conversation is else empty (enumeration yields no result). You can check your conditions accordingly.

```
var cust = new List<Table>
                       {
                           new Table {Conversation = 1, Id = 1, User = "Bob"},
                           new Table {Conversation = 1, Id = 2, User = "Jane"},
                           new Table {Conversation = 2, Id = 3, User = "Tim"},
                           new Table {Conversation = 2, Id = 4, User = "Lily"},
                           new Table {Conversation = 2, Id = 5, User = "Rick"}
                       };
        var names = new List<string> { "Rick", "Lily", "Tim" };


        var res = from x in cust
                  group x by x.Conversation
                  into y
                  where y.Select(z => z.User).Intersect(names).Count() == names.Count
                  select y.Key;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort @user1730658.

Comment: I have tried  the code above @Roshni but it didnt do the job. I will try again and back to you. Thanks again..

Comment: Hi @Roshni, i have tested again. because I am querying linq to sql it wont support that operation. The error says "base {System.SystemException} = {"Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator."}", Thank you for the effort.

Comment: Okay. I had tried with EF and it worked. Will try with Linq to SQL

Comment: I tried and its working with linqtosql for me. we just need to call ToList() on entity on which we are querying. eg if your collection is context.Employees then in linq will do context.Employees.ToList(). it worked for me. Hope for you too.

Comment: Yeah @Roshni that is work like u said. But it wont give me the result what i expected exactly. For example , if I filter , "var names = new List<string> { "Rick", "Lily" };" it stil gives me conversation id 2. but there is no uniq conversation between Rick and Lily. I want to uniquely compare them. Thanks Roshni for your time and help. I appreciated really.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for your help and answers. The following code did the trick and gives me the result what I wanted. Thank you Kristof for providing this code and your effort. I have attached order by clause in second query otherwise it wont gives the right result. Hope this helps someone who need similar stuff.

```
var users1 = new List<String> { "Bob", "Jane" };
var users2 = new List<String> { "Bob", "Jane", "Tim" };

var tableData = new List<YourTable>
    {
        new YourTable {foreignKey = 1, name = "Bob"},
        new YourTable {foreignKey = 1, name = "Jane"},
        new YourTable {foreignKey = 2, name = "Tim"},
        new YourTable {foreignKey = 2, name = "Lily"},
        new YourTable {foreignKey = 2, name = "Rick"},
    };



var rawData = (from t in tableData
               group t by t.foreignKey into users
               select users).ToList();

var key = (from d in rawData
           where d.Select(u => u.name).OrderBy(s=> s).SequenceEqual(users2.OrderBy(s=>s))
           select d.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```