# Select parent records with all children in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

- parent
- child
- parentchild

There is a many to many relationship between parent and child, realised with a parentchild  join table.

I'm looking for a query which will give me all the parents for a given list of child ids.
BUT - it has to match exactly, i.e. the parent has to match only if it has EXACTLY the given child id set, i.e. not less, but also not more (I'm struggle with the "not more" part).

I have a similar requirement as this: [Select Parent Record With All Children in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480742/select-parent-record-with-all-children-in-sql)
except that the children can have **multiple** parents.

To give a concrete example:

```
select * from parent

parent_id  name
------------------------------------
1          Parent 1
2          Parent 2

select * from child

child_id  name
------------------------------------
1         Child 1
2         Child 2
3         Child 3

select * from parent_child

parent_child_id  parent_id  child_id
------------------------------------
1                1          1
2                1          2
3                1          3
4                2          1
5                2          3
```

I.e. if providing child ids 1,2,3 must return parent id **1**, since only parent 1 is linked to all 3 given child ids.

Providing child ids 1 and 3, must return parent id **2**, since only parent 2 is linked to **only** child 1 and 3

This is my 1st question on here - hope it's ok!

Comment: Surely parent 2 is linked to child_id values 1 and 3 in the data supplied?

Comment: Hi Mark - you're absolutely right. I fixed the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select parent_id
from parent_child
group by parent_id
having count(child_id) = 2 and
       count(case when child_id in (1,3) then child_id end) = 2
```

- for child_id set (1,3). For child_id set (1,2,3), update the `in` condition accordingly, and change **both** `= 2` conditions to be `= 3`.

Comment: This works... but when I have large dataset the query just churns... seems the aggregation causes too much thrashing. It's used in an "parent.id in (...) statement. Any thoughts on how to improve the speed?

Comment: Figured it out. Just needed to add another join from the outer query. Works like a charm. Thanks!