# LINQ Query to find all tags?

Tags: linq

I have an application that manages documents called Notes. Like a blog, Notes can be searched for matches against one or more Tags, which are contained in a Note.Tags collection property. A Tag has Name and ID properties, and matches are made against the ID. A user can specify multiple tags to match against, in which case a Note must contain all Tags specified to match.

I have a very complex LINQ query to perform a Note search, with extension methods and looping. Quite frankly, it has a real code smell to it. I want to rewrite the query with something much simpler. I know that if I made the Tag a simple string, I could use something like this:

```
var matchingNotes = from n in myNotes
                    where n.Tags.All(tag => searchTags.Contains(tag))
```

Can I do something that simple if my model uses a Tag object with an ID? What would the query look like. Could it be written in fluent syntax? what would that look like?

Comment: I don't think your query does as you think - it enforces that the note is **only** tagged with the tags specified. It doesn't check that it has all the ones that *are* specified...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478874/how-do-i-retrieve-items-that-are-tagged-with-all-the-supplied-tags-in-linq/3479273#3479273

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can find notes that have the relevant tags in a single LINQ expression:

```
IQueryable<Note> query = ... // top part of query

query = query.Where(note => searchTags.All(st =>
    note.Tags.Any(notetag => notetag.Id == st.Id)));
```

Unfortunately there is no “fluent syntax” equivalent for `All` and `Any`, so the best you can do there is

```
query = from note in query
        where searchTags.All(st =>
            note.Tags.Any(notetag => notetag.Id == st.Id))
        select note;
```

which is not that much better either.

Comment: The query throws this error: 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'Tag'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.'

Comment: It works fine for me, so there must be something about your code that you haven’t told us. Are you sure that `Tag.Id` is of type `string` for example?

Comment: Actually, TagID is Type GUID.

Comment: @David Veeneman: I believe I have answered your question as stated. If you think I haven’t, please edit the question to clarify what information is still missing. If you have any further questions, you can post a new, separate question.

Comment: I believe I found the problem--it is with LINQ to Entities, not with your query. There appears to be a problem with the All() method in LTE. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879411/entity-framework-unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-closure-type.

Answer (score 0):

For starters see my comment; I suspect the query is wrong anyway! I would simplifiy it, by simply enforcing separately that each tag exists:

```
IQueryable<Note> query = ... // top part of query
foreach(var tagId in searchTagIds) {
    var tmpId = tagId; // modified closures...
    query = query.Where(note => note.Tags.Any(t => t.Id == tmpId));
}
```

This should have the net effect of enforcing all the tags specified are present and accounted for.

Comment: hi, can you answer [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/2034468.aspx?Linq+Update+a+row+if+new+rows+are+inserted+in+another+table)

Answer (score 0):

Timwi's solution works in most dialects of LINQ, but not in Linq to Entities. I did find a single-statement LINQ query that works, courtesy of *ReSharper*. Basically, I wrote a foreach block to do the search, and ReSharper offered to convert the block to a LINQ statement--I had no idea it could do this.

I let ReSharper perform the conversion, and here is what it gave me:

```
return searchTags.Aggregate<Tag, IQueryable<Note>>(DataStore.ObjectContext.Notes, (current, tag) => current.Where(n => n.Tags.Any(t => t.Id == tag.Id)).OrderBy(n => n.Title));
```

I read my Notes collection from a database, using Entity Framework 4. DataStore is the custom class I use to manage my EF4 connection; it holds the EF4 ObjectContext as a property.