# Filter the "Includes" table on Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

This is for Entity Framework for .NET 3.5:

I have the need to query a table and include a collection of the "many" table of a one-to-many relationship.  I'm trying to filter that collection as part of the query - I'm pretty new to Entity Framework, and I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Simplified example: Author has Books, and Book has an IsFiction column.  I want a filtered list of authors, along with all fiction books.

Without the filter, it's easy:

```
var q = from a in db.Authors.Include("Books")
        where a.BirthYear > 1900
        select a;
```

I can filter after the fact, something like:

```
var fictionBooks = a.Books.Where(b => b.IsFiction);
```

But the problem is that the original query already ran, and included those results, which is unnecessary database processing.

I can query separately, like:

```
var q = from a in db.Authors where a.BirthYear > 1900 select a;
foreach (var a in q)
{
    var books = from b in db.Books 
                where ((b.Author.Id == a.Id) && (b.IsFiction))
                select b;
}
```

But of course that's one call for every author, which I want to avoid as well.

I can go backwards, like:

```
var allBooks = from b in db.Books.Include("Author")
               where b.IsFiction
               select b;
```

But then I'm back to the original problem, except now on the author side instead of the book side.

There must be a solution that encompasses everything - I can do it in SQL pretty easily:

```
select * from author a
left join book b on a.id = b.author_id and b.is_fiction = 1
where a.birth_year > 1900
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Vote for filtered Include [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/47)!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The forward way:

```
var q = from a in db.Authors.Include("Books")
        where a.BirthYear > 1900
        select new {
            Author = a,
            FictionBooks = a.Books.Where(b => b.IsFiction)
        };
```

Another way, derived from the SQL at the bottom of your question:

```
var q = from a in db.Authors
        from b in db.Books.Include("Author")
        where a.BirthYear > 1900 && b.IsFiction && a.Id == b.Author.Id
        select new { Author = a, Book = b };
```

The main difference between these two is that the first one will basically give you a collection of authors plus the list of fiction books for each author (which may be empty); while the second will give you a collection of author/books pairs (so it doesn’t return any authors with no fiction books).

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I'm hoping to actually get a collection of Author objects if possible, not anonymous typed objects.  On the same note, if I did take that anonymously typed object and enumerated the Author's Books collection, wouldn't it return the entire collection of books, not just the fiction ones?

Comment: @Joe Enos: If you enumerated the `Author`’s `Books` collection, yes, of course. That’s why there’s the `FictionBooks` property :)

Comment: If you are hoping to get `Author` objects whose `Books` collection is *explicitly incomplete* (because it’s filtered by fictionness), then this is not really how LINQ is intended to work. Each `Author` object returned by a LINQ query is intended to represent the `Author` entity in the DB, not an altered version of it.

Comment: @Joe Enos: I have only actually used LINQ-to-SQL, but not LINQ-to-Entities, so I don’t know the details. [The difference between the two has already bitten me earlier today.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539404/x/3539436#3539436) I recommend you look at the SQL query actually sent to the server if you want to be really sure what it does under the hood.