# Entity Framework include Where

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

If I have a query that looks like this:

```
var forms = repo.GetForms().Where(f => f.SubForms.Any(sf => sf.Classes.Any(c => c.TermId == termId)));
```

From this you can see my schema is as follows:

`SubForm` has many `Class` which has many `Term`.

What I want:

All `SubForms` with their `Classes` In a particular `Term`.

What is happening now is that I get all the `SubForm` that has any `Class` in a particular `Term`. That means that `SubForm` comes back with **ALL** child `Class` and not just the ones related to the `Term`.

For eg. I have 2 terms, a subform with 2 classes in each term. This query brings back 4 classes instead of the 2 in that particular term.

Is there any `Include('Expression')` that I can use to say that I only want to include all classes based on a condition? Or is my query wrong?

Comment: The first `Any` is supposed to be a `Where`, right? Otherwise your query would just return a `bool`, saying "Is there any subform which has classes with terms with the given termId, yes or no?"

Comment: @Slauma Sorry, there is also another level on top of that expression, I'll edit it, sorry

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
var subForms = repo.GetSubForms.Select(sf = new {
        SubForm = sf,
        Classes = sf.Classes.Where(c => c.TermId == termId)
    }).ToList()
    .Select(t => t.SubForm)
    .ToList();
```

**UPDATE:** based on @Slauma's comment:

If you want to load `SubForm`s that they have any `Class` that has a `Term` by `termId`, you can go from end to begin; like this:

```
var subForms = repo.Terms.Where(t => t.Id == termId).Select(t => new {
        Term = t,
        Class = t.Class,
        SubForm = t.Class.SubForm
    }).ToList()
    .Select(t => t.SubForm).ToList();
```

**OR** in a easiest way, you can use `Include` on your `Term`, see:

```
var subForms = repo.Terms.Include("Class.SubForm").Where(t => t.Id == termId)
                   .Select(t => t.Class.SubForm).ToList();
```

**NOTE:** As I can understand from your question, you have a relationship like this:

```
SubForm has_many Class has_many Term
```

But, your provided code is showing a relationship like this one:

```
SubForm has_many Class
Term has_many Class
```

If you can, put your entities in question, or explain their relationship more please. Thank you.

Comment: You still need the filter between `GetSubForms` and `Select`: `Where(sf => sf.Classes.Any(c => c.TermId == termId))`. Otherwise you would load *all* subforms from the DB, including subforms with classes with no matching termId.

Comment: @Slauma OK, really I don't understand the question completely; So I update my answer; Thank you :)

Comment: True, the first `Any` in the question is confusing. I've just written a comment under the question because I believe he meant actually a `Where`.

Comment: @Javad_Amiry I edited the question with the added complexity.

Comment: @Lolcoder so you can use the `end-to-begin` pattern; I haven't Win and VS just now to test the codes; so test them please and let me know if there is any problem.

Answer (score 4):

An `Include(Where Expression)` does not exist. If you use eager loading with Include you will always load all the elements.

There is a way around this by using projections. The basic idea is you will select a new anonymous type with the property you want and another property with the filtered navigational items. EF will link those together and as a result you will fake a `Include(Where ... )`

[Check this for an example](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/use-projections-and-a-repository-to-fake-a-filtered-eager-load/).

Comment: Minor nit: `Include(Expression)` does exist as the System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions.Include extension method, but has a totally different meaning. It's used as an alternative to string literals: `repo.Terms.Include(term => term.Classes)`.

Comment: Thnx. I've modified my answer

Answer (score 1):

You know sometimes I start getting lost in fancy LINQ extension methods and attempting to figure out how to eagerly load exactly what I want and resort to a very simple "join" concept.

```
var result = 
(from f in SubForums
from c in Classes
from t in Term
where t.TermId = 1
select new { SubForum = f, Class = c, Term = t }).ToList();
```

This is a simple join that uses predefined navigation properties (hence you don't have to specify the join condition).  You return an anonymous type with everything that you need.  The beauty of this is that Entity Framework will do the auto-fixup for you, therefor you're free to return the SubForum only from your method if you wish, it will automatically contain the Class and subsequent Term references.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact names of the relations, but it should be something along the lines of

```
repo.Terms
    .Include("Classes")
    .Include("Classes.SubForms")
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.TermId = termId);

// or 

repo.GetSubForms
    .Include("Classes")
    .Where(sf => sf.Classes.Where(c => c.TermId == termId));
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common request, it was difficult to find a solution to it when I was looking earlier this year.   I ended up using the solution included in the link below (I'm not sure this is the exact solution I found, but it's the same idea).  Hope this helps!

[Filter the "Includes" table on Entity Framework query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544864/filter-the-includes-table-on-entity-framework-query)

```
                //Found this method to filter our child objects instead of using .include()
                var Results = (from res in
                                   (from u in DataContext.User
                                    where u.Type.ToUpper() != "ADMIN"
                                    && u.StartDate <= DateTime.Now
                                    && (u.EndDate == null || u.EndDate >= DateTime.Now)
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        User = u,
                                        Access = u.Access.Where(a => a.StartDate <= DateTime.Now
                                                  && (a.EndDate == null || a.EndDate >= DateTime.Now))
                                    }
                                    )
                               select res);

                //The ToArray is neccesary otherwise the Access is not populated in the Users
                ReturnValue = Results.ToArray().Select(x => x.User).ToList();
```