# Linq Join one to many AND Criteria

Tags: linq, join, one-to-many

```
Product
+------------+-------------+------------+
| PID        | Name        | Model      |
+------------+-------------+------------+
|          1 | Mercedes    | xyz        |
|          2 | Audi        | yxz        |
|          3 | BMW         | zyx        |
+------------+-------------+------------+


ProductColor
+------------+-------------+------------+
| ID         | ProductID   | Color      |
+------------+-------------+------------+
|          1 | 1           | Red        |
|          2 | 1           | Blue       |
|          3 | 3           | Blue       |
+------------+-------------+------------+
```

I need to select ProductID's from ProductColor where **blue AND red?** How to write correct Linq Query?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you able to provide an example of your classes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve items that are tagged with all the supplied tags in linq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478874/how-do-i-retrieve-items-that-are-tagged-with-all-the-supplied-tags-in-linq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have relationships on the database tables, something like this should work:

c#:

```
var ProductIDs = ctx.Products.Where(p => p.Color.Contains("Red") && 
    p.Color.Contains("Blue")).Select(p => p.PID)
```

vb:

```
Dim ProductIDs = ctx.Products.Where(function(p) p.Color.Contains("Red") And
    p.Color.Contains("Blue")).Select(function(p) p.PID)
```

Comment: List<Product> Pr= data.Products.Where(x=> x.ProductColors.Where(y=> y.Color== "blue").Select(z=> z.ProductID).Contains(x.ID) && x.ProductColors.Where(y=> y.Color== "red").Select(z=> z.ProductID).Contains(x.ID)).ToList(); How to PredicateBuilder multi-criteria?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Product> Pr= data.Products.Where(x=> x.ProductColors.Where(y=>   
y.Color=="blue").Select(z=> z.ProductID).Contains(x.ID) && 
x.ProductColors.Where(y=> y.Color== "red").Select(z=> 
z.ProductID).Contains(x.ID)).ToList()
```

green
yellow
n

How to multi-criteria linq query?