# How to do a LINQ query with Split operation

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq query:

```
 MyClass myobj = (from p in Session.All<MyClass>()
                  where p.tags.Split(' ').Contains(searchTag) 
                  select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

When I run this, I get:

> System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot
>   be translated into a store expression.

What is a good way to do what I am attempting to do?

Comment: I would say, it's not possible. And that's not because of LINQ, it's because SQL does not provide that kind of functionality. And you should consider changing your DB structure and moving tags from the table to separate dictionary, linked using foreign key

Comment: SQL itself doesn't support that.

Comment: The question is why your `tags` column stores tags white-space separated. Create a new table with one row per tag.

Comment: Normalize the tags, then do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478874/how-do-i-retrieve-items-that-are-tagged-with-all-the-supplied-tags-in-linq/3479273#3479273

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem here is the db design, but assuming you have no control over this one idea is to split the query.

First retrieve any rows that contain the search tag anywhere within them.

```
List<MyClass> myobjs = (from p in Session.All<MyClass>()
                        where p.tags.Contains(searchTag) 
                        select p).ToList();
```

Then perform the correct tag search on the retrieved objects in memory.

```
MyClass myobj = myobjs.FirstOrDefault(m => m.tags.Split(' ').Contains(searchTag));
```

Comment: `AsEnumerable` would be preferable to `ToList` here.

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming tags = `tag1 tag2 tag3`, and searchTag is `tag2` you can just do:

```
 MyClass myobj = (from p in Session.All<MyClass>()
              where p.tags.IndexOf(searchTag) > -1
              and searchTag.IndexOf(" ") == -1
              select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Not sure that this is correct. The original post suggests that the "tags" field contains a space delimited list of tags, and the parameter "searchTag" should match one token in this list.