# SQL Query using IN but where all results have to have the same grouping ID

Tags: sql, grouping

Unsure exactly how to put this question so apologies for the awkward phrasing, generally when I know how to properly describe a problem I can use the site search to look for it, or Google etc.

Anyway, simple enough issue - I'm querying a link / junction table with a variable array of AttributeIds, for example the IDs 14 and 17. Using the following table:

http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/5999/setattributecombo.gif

The only valid result I want to return from this query is where the ProductSetId is the same, so instead of 'IN' I want something like

```
WHERE AttributeIds IN 14,17 AND ProductSetId is the same
```

In the above example, the only valid result would be 5 but if I use an IN query I get 2,5,7 as results.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the table you are referring to

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query: Simulating an "AND" over several rows instead of sub-querying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163887/sql-query-simulating-an-and-over-several-rows-instead-of-sub-querying)

Comment: The table is essentially as you see above with the exception of a primary key column, it's a junction table to only has the two columns plus primary key. I will read that possible duplicate, hopefully it's what I'm after.

Comment: What is the output if you also have a row {17,7}?

Comment: "is the same" is not good enough; you have to specify somehow that you want 5 and not 2 or 7

Comment: @Cosmin: OP has written "In the above example, the only valid result would be 5 but if I use an IN query I get 2,5,7 as results.". Please read carefully.

Comment: @Jim Garrison - The output would then be 5,7 as there are two 'groups' that contain all those elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ProductSetID, COUNT(*) AS CountOfMatchingRows
From MyTable
WHERE AttributeId IN (14,17 )
GROUP BY ProductSetID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Don't suppose anyone knows the name for this type of problem, or if it has a better name than how I described it in my question title? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to perform Relational Division.  A good article on various methods is over at Simple-Talk.  http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/