# SQL select a parent with children only in

Tags: sql, tags, parent, subset

if you have parent table

```
create table parent (
  pid int not null,
  name varchar(255)
)
```

and a parent-child join table

```
create table parent_child (
  pid int not null,
  cid int not null,
  foreign key (pid) references parent(pid),
  foreign key (cid) references child(cid)
)
create table child(
  cid int not null,
  name varchar(255)
)
```

How can I find all parent's names where all their children have names in the following list ('dave','henry','myriam','jill').

I don't want to see a parent if they have a child with a different name, but if they have 1 or more children and all their children have names in the list I want to see the parent's name.

I did find this https://stackoverflow.com/a/304314/1916621 that will help me find a parent with children of the exactly those names, but I can't figure out how to the parents who only have children with names in a subset of that list.

Extra points if someone knows performance tradeoff for different approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    p.pid, 
    p.name
FROM 
    parent p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM 
        parent_child pc 
        JOIN child c 
            ON pc.cid = c.cid
            AND c.name NOT IN ('dave','henry','myriam','jill')
    WHERE 
        p.pid = pc.pid
) AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM 
        parent_child pc 
        JOIN child c 
            ON pc.cid = c.cid
            AND c.name IN ('dave','henry','myriam','jill')
    WHERE 
        p.pid = pc.pid
)
```

Another method... no sub-queries, but additional `DISTINCT` needed to eliminate duplication of `parent` records from joining to the `parent_child` table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.pid, 
    p.name
FROM 
    parent p 
    JOIN parent_child pc_exists ON pc_exists.pid = p.pid
    JOIN child c_exists 
        ON c_exists.cid = pc_exists.cid
        AND c_exists.name IN ('dave','henry','myriam','jill')
    LEFT JOIN parent_child pc_notExists ON pc_notExists.pid = p.pid
    LEFT JOIN child c_notExists 
        ON c_notExists.cid = pc_notExists.cid
        AND c_notExists.name NOT IN ('dave','henry','myriam','jill')
WHERE
    c_notExists.cid IS NULL
```

Comment: I think is the first correct solution... but if there is a large db with many different names would the select in the "where not exists" take too long?  Wonder if it would be possible w/o sub queries.

Comment: @user1916621 Let me add an example without sub-queries, but I'll bet that both queries will either use the same execution plan, or that the    `not exists / exists` query posted here will be faster... since I'll have to add an additional `distinct` operator to the other method.  The best way to know which way is faster is to try both.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my moderate bet:

Sample tables:

**Parent**

```
PID     NAME
1       dad john
2       mum sandy
3       dad frank
4       mum kate
5       mum jean
```

**Child**

```
CID     NAME
11      dave
22      maryam
33      henry
44      maryam
16      jill
17      lina
23      jack
34      jill
55      dave
```

**Parent_Child**

```
PID     CID
1       11
1       16
1       17
2       22
3       33
4       44
2       23
5       55
3       34
```

Query:

```
select p.pid, p.name, 
group_concat(c.name) as children
from parent as p
inner join parent_child as pc
on p.pid = pc.pid
join child as c
on pc.cid = c.cid
where c.name
in ('dave','henry','maryam','jill')
group by p.pid
;
```

Results:

```
PID     NAME        CHILDREN
1       dad john    dave,jill
2       mum sandy   maryam
3       dad frank   henry,jill
4       mum kate    maryam
5       mum jean    dave
```

- [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09ce6/1)

---

### Using REGEXP and GROUP_CONCAT

It is something much better than `in` or `find_in_set` for SQL. The change I did, I used the list as a `comma delimitted string` ;)

*But the issue here: that group_concat string order has to be found in the comman delimitted string.* Unless we make the `REGEXP` much efficient :)

Query:

```
select x.pid, x.name,
x.children from(
select p.pid, p.name, 
group_concat(c.name) as children,
  count(c.name) as counts
from parent as p
inner join parent_child as pc
on p.pid = pc.pid
join child as c
on pc.cid = c.cid
group by p.pid) as x
where 'dave,maryam,henry,jill'
REGEXP x.children
;
```

Results:

```
PID     NAME        CHILDREN
3       dad frank   henry,jill
4       mum kate    maryam
5       mum jean    dave
```

***[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b12f/14)**

Comment: +1 For going through the effort of creating the Sql Fiddle, but I think `PID 1` should be excluded because this parent also has a child that's not in the list (`lina`)....

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson precisely OP wants the parents whose one child ore more children (=all children of one parent) in the list. Tricky `intersect` type of a query, I salute you :) +1

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson I just want to get your thoughts on the update I did with `REGEXP`. Do you think with a better regex pattern this could be effective?

Comment: It looks like its getting the correct results (+1)... as far as efficiency, I'm not sure - probably depends pretty heavily on the data involved.  The `REGEXP` will obfuscate any indexes, so that will probably have a bigger performance hit than would be saved / spent by tweaking the regular expression...  I'm not much of a regex guy, so unfortunately I can't recommend a more efficient pattern to try... if you end up comparing this approach vs one of the other solutions, I'd be very curious to know how it compares.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson thanks for sharing the info. Well I tested out both your queries. Sorry to haunt you on this. Something weird in the way I am executing perhaps, doesn't seem to result in what we need. [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b12f/35)