# How to make a division in SQL

Tags: sql

Let's say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    Order_ID int,
    Product_ID int,
    PRIMARY KEY(Order_ID,Product_ID)
);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3), (3,3), (3,4);
```

How can i get all orders which contains product id's 2 and 3?

I want to get results

```
Order_ID 
--
 1
 2
```

The result must be orders 1 and 2, because the order 1 has products {1,2,3} — it has subset {2,3}. On the other hand, the order 3's product set is {3,4} — it doesn't have subset {2,3}, so it must not returned in the result.

Comment: a subset that you would define/resolve according which rule ?

Comment: What?  Please clarify. How does 1,2 relate to your example data?

Comment: What do you mean by "subset of the 2 ID"?

Comment: I want as result, those ID's which have ALL the P_id's of the 2 ID.  The 2 ID has P_ID=2 and 3. So i want {2,3} be a subset of an other sulution. The ID=1 has P_id={1,2,3} so it includes the 2. On the other hand the ID=3 has P_id={3,4}, that does not include complete the 2 ID so it is not result

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query: Simulating an "AND" over several rows instead of sub-querying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163887/sql-query-simulating-an-and-over-several-rows-instead-of-sub-querying)

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly:

```
Select ID
From table_name
where P_ID = 2
```

Comment: In this example that will work, but let's say that the last 2 values are (3,2) (3,4). It will return the ID 3 but it should not. I want to get the ID that have ALL P_ID of the given ID (here ID=2)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to select all the lines that correspond to your subset.
Then group by order, and count how many correspondance you have. If it's equal to the size of your subset, then the order is eligible.

```
SELECT orders.order_id
FROM orders
WHERE orders.product_id in (2, 3)
GROUP BY orders.order_id
HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
```

Note that this works because you have define `PRIMARY KEY(Order_ID,Product_ID)`, which is a very good idea!

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f448f/5/0)