# Ger rows with 2 specifical occurrences

Tags: sql, oracle

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | X |
| 1 | Z |
| 2 | X |
| 2 | Y |
| 3 | Y |
| 4 | X |
| 4 | Y |
| 4 | Z |
| 5 | Y |

I want get all distinct values of Column A that has a row with Column B equal to X and other row with Column B equal to 'Y'

The result will be like this:

| Column_A |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 4 |

I tried in this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_A
FROM TABLE
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_A
   FROM TABLE
   WHERE COLUMN_B = 'X') SUBTABLE 
ON TABLE.COLUMN_A = SUBTABLE.COLUMN_A
WHERE TABLE.COLUMN_B = 'Y';
```

I think that this solution works but isn't optimum

Thanks a have a nice day

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query: Simulating an "AND" over several rows instead of sub-querying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163887/sql-query-simulating-an-and-over-several-rows-instead-of-sub-querying)

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a simple aggregation by:

- filtering only Column_B values you're interested in
- aggregating for distinct values of Column_B
- checking the amount of distinct values equals 2

```
SELECT Column_A
FROM tab
WHERE Column_B IN ('X', 'Y')
GROUP BY Column_A
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Column_B) = 2
```

or you can use the `INTERSECT` operator between:

- the records having Column_B = 'X'
- the records having Column_B = 'Y'

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column_A FROM tab WHERE Column_B = 'X'
INTERSECT 
SELECT DISTINCT Column_A FROM tab WHERE Column_B = 'Y'
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/vmSO7sDM).