# fastest way to match the values retrieved by SELECT with elements in Array (Oracle PLSQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the table `my_table` that may looks like:

```
+----+--------------------+
| id | some_other_columns |
+====+====================+
| 2  | data_2             |
+----+--------------------+
| 4  | data_4             |
+----+--------------------+
| 6  | data_6             |
+----+--------------------+
```

and have the array `my_array` that is defined as follows:

```
type t_numbers_type is table of number;
my_array t_numbers_type := t_numbers_type(2, 4, 6);
```

Q: I am looking for the fastest way to determine if list of all ids in my_table are **identical** with my_array?

i.e.: want to make sure that in the table my_table there are only 3 ids each one can be found in my_array

what I've tried so far the naïve straight-forward approach:

```
l_cnt        := 0;
l_missing_id := false;

for r_rec in (select id
                from my_table)
loop
  l_cnt := l_cnt +1;
  if r_rec.id not member of my_array then
    l_missing_id := true;
    exit;   
  end if;
end loop;

if l_cnt = my_array.count and not l_missing_id then
  dbms_output.putline('OK');
else
  dbms_output.putline('Not OK');
end if;
```

is there more direct way, something like:
`exists(select * from my_table where id in my_array)`

or maybe:
`not exists(select * from my_table where id not in my_array)`

Comment: If you need only to check identifiers, then you may refer to [SQL query: Simulating an "AND" over several rows instead of sub-querying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/163887/2778710). If you want other columns along with identifiers, then you may `left join` in to the list turned into table with `table(my_array)`

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [TABLE() FUNCTION](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/tutorial_GSOTSK8FWLYZOG5CJJ9KPX7RX.html#:%7E:text=What%20Is%20a%20Table%20Function,processed%20in%20a%20SQL%20statement.) in Oracle PLSQL.

As you are asking:

> Q: I am looking for the fastest way to determine if list of all ids in
> my_table are identical with my_array?

The more direct way to achieve would be :

```
select count(*) into l_cnt 
from my_table
where id in (select column_value from table(my_array));
```

Comment: would that works if the table has the values for example: 2,4,6,8 ?