# Oracle SQL select from multiple condition but with has same id's

Tags: sql, oracle

I will retrieve data fom oracle database. It has table as you see in picture below. (Table Name is ATTRIBUTE_TAB)

I want to query:

if (VALUE_NO='6000' VALUE_TEXT='TEMPERED' VALUE_TEXT=BLUE) but these rows has to be same id.

I explained in picture below.

My Query is

```
SELECT * FROM ATTRIBUTE_TAB
WHERE VALUE_NO='6000' OR VALUE_TEXT='TEMPERED'OR VALUE_TEXT='BLUE
```

but I couldn't integrate the id status into the code.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query: Simulating an "AND" over several rows instead of sub-querying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163887/sql-query-simulating-an-and-over-several-rows-instead-of-sub-querying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation as the following:

```
SELECT * FROM ATTRIBUTE_TAB
  WHERE ID IN
  (
    SELECT ID FROM ATTRIBUTE_TAB
    WHERE VALUE_NO='6000' OR VALUE_TEXT='TEMPERED'OR VALUE_TEXT='BLUE'
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 -- or maybe HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ATTRIBUTE) = 3 if duplicates are possible 
  )
ORDER BY ID, ATTRIBUTE DESC
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/dtIdMxI8)

Comment: Its worked perfectly. Thanx. What is the ide a of using HAVING COUNT(*)=3. I f i want to add one more condition, should it be HAVING COUNT(*)=4 ?

Comment: The use of `COUNT(*) = 3`  is to ensure that three rows are returned for each ID group, (one row for each condition), so yes, if you want to add another condition that should be met, use `COUNT(*) = 4`

Comment: Note that, if an ID could have duplicate attributes, i.e. *more than one attribute with the same color*, then use the `count(distinct attribute) = 3`  to ensure that the returned ID group has three different attributes that meet the specified criteria. (I don't think you have this case anyway)

Comment: Thanx for extra infos . In this table every ID has one attribute.  But I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to *reformat* source table so that every "value" fits into its own column (that's what the `temp` CTE in my query does). Then it is really simple to extract data you need.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with attribute_tab (id, attribute, value_no, value_text) as
  2    (select 1, 'WIDTH', 6000, null        from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'COLOR', null, 'BLUE'      from dual union all
  4     select 1, 'GLASS', null, 'TEMPERED'  from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 2, 'WIDTH', 6500, null        from dual union all
  7     select 2, 'COLOR', null, 'YELLOW'    from dual union all
  8     select 2, 'GLASS', null, 'BIRD SAFE' from dual union all
  9     --
 10     select 4, 'WIDTH', 6000, null        from dual union all
 11     select 4, 'COLOR', null, 'BLUE'      from dual union all
 12     select 4, 'GLASS', null, 'TEMPERED'  from dual union all
 13     --
 14     select 6, 'WIDTH', 6500, null        from dual union all
 15     select 6, 'COLOR', null, 'BLUE'      from dual union all
 16     select 6, 'GLASS', null, 'BIRD SAFE' from dual
 17    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
 18  temp as
 19    (select id,
 20       max(case when attribute = 'WIDTH' then value_no end) width,
 21       max(case when attribute = 'COLOR' then value_text end) color,
 22       max(case when attribute = 'GLASS' then value_text end) glass
 23     from attribute_tab
 24     group by id
 25    )
 26  select *
 27  from temp
 28  where width = 6000
 29    and color = 'BLUE'
 30    and glass = 'TEMPERED'
 31  order by id;

        ID      WIDTH COLOR     GLASS
---------- ---------- --------- ---------
         1       6000 BLUE      TEMPERED
         4       6000 BLUE      TEMPERED

SQL>
```

Comment: Actually i am also searching transpose the rows to column. Many thanx.