# Subset match in Oracle

Tags: oracle, subset

I've the following two tables, `pod_label` & `service_selector`:

```sql
create table pod_label (
    name varchar2(256),
    key varchar2(256),
    value varchar2(256)
);

insert into pod_label (name, key, value)
values ('p1', 'l1', '1');
insert into pod_label (name, key, value)
values ('p1', 'l2', '2');
insert into pod_label (name, key, value)
values ('p1', 'l3', '3');

insert into pod_label (name, key, value)
values ('p2', 'l1', '1');

insert into pod_label (name, key, value)
values ('p3', 'l1', 'N/A');
```

| NAME | KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | l1 | 1 |
| p1 | l2 | 2 |
| p1 | l3 | 3 |
| p2 | l1 | 1 |
| p3 | l1 | N/A |

```sql
create table service_selector (
    name varchar2(256),
    key varchar2(256),
    value varchar2(256)
);

insert into service_selector (name, key, value)
values ('s1', 'l1', '1');
insert into service_selector (name, key, value)
values ('s1', 'l2', '2');
```

| NAME | KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | l1 | 1 |
| s1 | l2 | 2 |

I'd like to find `name` in `pod_label` such that the corresponding `(key, value)` pairs are a superset of those of `s1` in `service_selector`. In the above example, `p1` is a match, while `p2` & `p3` are not.

A straight `JOIN` isn't going to do it. Is there a way w/out resorting to a PL/SQL function?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the types:

```sql
CREATE TYPE key_value_pair AS OBJECT(
  key   VARCHAR2(256),
  value VARCHAR2(256)
);

CREATE TYPE key_value_list AS TABLE OF key_value_pair;
```

Then you can aggregate the values into collections and use the `SUBMULTISET OF` operator to compare collections and ensure that one is a sub-set of the other:

```sql
SELECT name, key, value
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         key,
         value,
         CAST(
           COLLECT(key_value_pair(key, value)) OVER (PARTITION BY name)
           AS key_value_list
         ) AS kvs
  FROM   pod_label
) pl
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   service_selector ss
         GROUP BY name
         HAVING CAST(
                  COLLECT(key_value_pair(ss.key, ss.value))
                  AS key_value_list
                ) SUBMULTISET OF pl.kvs
       );
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| NAME | KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | l1 | 1 |
| p1 | l2 | 2 |
| p1 | l3 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AO55W_6O)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the same approach as in this question: [SQL query: Simulating an "AND" over several rows instead of sub-querying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163887/sql-query-simulating-an-and-over-several-rows-instead-of-sub-querying?r=Saves_AllUserSaves). The idea is:

- match rows by the list of values
- count number of matched rows per key
- select only those keys that have number of matches equal to a number of criteria (the length of the list)

To extrapolate this approach for multiple lists identified by some column you may use analytic `count` with `partition by` that column.

```
with vals_per_service as (
  /*Number of criteria per service*/
  select
    s.*,
    count(1) over(partition by name) as s_cnt
  from service_selector s
)
, pod_match as (
  select
    s.name as service_name,
    p.*,
    s.s_cnt,
    /*Number of matches per pod and service*/
    count(1) over(partition by s.name, p.name) as match_cnt
  from vals_per_service s
    left join pod_label p
    on p.key = s.key
    and p.value = s.value
)
select *
from pod_match
/*Pods that matched by all criteria*/
where s_cnt = match_cnt
--  or name is null /*If you want selectors without matches*/
order by 1,2
```

Which for this sample data (extended by other selectors):

```
select *
from pod_label
```

| NAME | KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | l1 | 1 |
| p1 | l2 | 2 |
| p1 | l3 | 3 |
| p2 | l1 | 1 |
| p2 | l3 | 3 |
| p3 | l1 | N/A |

```
select *
from service_selector
```

| NAME | KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | l1 | 1 |
| s1 | l2 | 2 |
| s2 | l1 | 1 |
| s3 | l1 | 1 |
| s3 | l3 | none |

returns:

| SERVICE_NAME | NAME | KEY | VALUE | S_CNT | MATCH_CNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | p1 | l1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| s1 | p1 | l2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| s2 | p1 | l1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| s2 | p2 | l1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7nzAEsLx)