# How to use SQL to filter a Column to equal to Two Conditions Simultaneously?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, relational-database, toad

I have a table called PM_BATCH_ST like this:

| BATCH_ID | RESULT |
| --- | --- |
| 1000564932 | ISC |
| 1000564932 | LLC |
| 1000585739 | ISC |
| 1000585739 | LLC |
| 1000384769 | ISC |
| 1000384769 | LLC |
| 1000384757 | LLC |
| 1000888940 | ISC |

Can I filter the Table to obtain BATCH_IDs that have both an ISC entry and an LLC entry?
So the Answer I would like is:

1000564932

1000585739

1000384769

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query: Simulating an "AND" over several rows instead of sub-querying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163887/sql-query-simulating-an-and-over-several-rows-instead-of-sub-querying)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT BATCH_ID
FROM PM_BATCH_ST
WHERE RESULT IN ('ISC', 'LLC')
GROUP BY BATCH_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT RESULT) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following would do:

```
select distinct batch_id
from  PM_BATCH_ST a
where a.result = 'ISC' and 
  exists (
    select 1
    from  PM_BATCH_ST b
    where a.batch_id=b.batch_id 
      and b.result='LLC'
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

For 2 values, I would just self-`JOIN` and use a `WHERE` clause like this:

```sql
SELECT st1.BATCH_ID
FROM PM_BATCH_ST st1
JOIN PM_BATCH_ST st2 ON st1.BATCH_ID = st2.BATCH_ID
WHERE st1.RESULT = 'ISC' AND st2.RESULT = 'LLC'
```

That should give you all `BATCH_ID` having both `ISC` and `LLC` as `RESULT`

SQL Fiddle results in:

| BATCH_ID |
| --- |
| 1000564932 |
| 1000585739 |
| 1000384769 |

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `INTERSECT`

```
SELECT BATCH_ID
FROM PM_BATCH_ST
WHERE RESULT = 'ISC'

INTERSECT

SELECT BATCH_ID
FROM PM_BATCH_ST
WHERE RESULT = 'LLC'
```

Result:

```
BATCH_ID
1000384769
1000564932
1000585739
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE PM_BATCH_ST (
    BATCH_ID INT,
    RESULT TEXT
);


INSERT INTO PM_BATCH_ST (BATCH_ID, RESULT)
VALUES
    (1000564932, 'ISC'),
    (1000564932, 'LLC'),
    (1000585739, 'ISC'),
    (1000585739, 'LLC'),
    (1000384769, 'ISC'),
    (1000384769, 'LLC'),
    (1000384757, 'LLC'),
    (1000888940, 'ISC');

/* @Qubicon has the most tighten-up answer. Below is another way of doing it*/

WITH ISC_table AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM PM_BATCH_ST
  WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, RESULT) IN ('ISC')
),
    LLC_table AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM PM_BATCH_ST
  WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, RESULT) IN ('LLC')
)

SELECT
  t1.BATCH_ID AS BATCH_ID
FROM ISC_table AS t1
INNER JOIN LLC_table AS t2
ON t1.BATCH_ID = t2.BATCH_ID;
```

| BATCH_ID |
| --- |
| 1000564932 |
| 1000585739 |
| 1000384769 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OIXWC-7z)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you can achieve desired result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.BATCH_ID
FROM PM_BATCH_ST a
INNER JOIN PM_BATCH_ST b ON a.BATCH_ID = b.BATCH_ID
WHERE a.RESULT = 'ISC' AND b.RESULT = 'LLC';
```