# Correct SQL for checking for bad combinations

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working in an oracle sql database and have these two tables, one with a list of bad attribute combinations, and then another that has a list of users with their attributes. Like so:

| ComboID | Item1 | Item2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ice Cream | Hot Sauce |
| 2 | Asparagus | Chocolate |
| 3 | Peanut Butter | Steak |
| 4 | Asparagus | Ice Cream |

| UserAttributeID | User | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | Ice Cream |
| 2 | B2 | Asparagus |
| 3 | A1 | Chocolate |
| 4 | B2 | Ice Cream |
| 5 | C3 | Steak |
| 6 | C3 | Ice Cream |
| 7 | C3 | Chocolate |

In this case, I'd want the user B2 to be flagged, but not A1 or C3.

My expected result would be something like:

| User | Bad_Combo_ID |
| --- | --- |
| B2 | 4 |

Generally, everything I've tried has seemed either needlessly convoluted and slow or would have flagged A1 and C3 in the above example.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to specify the expected result.

Comment: @Isolated, those markdown style tables really waste screen height...

Comment: Have you been able to write a query that produces the expected result? You complain that your attempt was "slow". Could you please show this query? Otherwise, you maybe will get answers with a similar query that will be slow, too.

Comment: @jarlh

Sure thing - sorry, new here.  My expected result would be something like:

| Bad_Combo_User_ID | User | Bad_Combo_ID |
|-------------------|------|--------------|
| 1                 | B2   | 4            |
| 2                 | D4   | 2            |
| 3                 | E5   | 3            |

Comment: @JonasMetzler I added a table ID, admittedly mostly on habit. That's not related to UserAttributeID or ComboID, but would be the ID for the specific user/bad info combination.  D4 and E5 would just be different users that would have different bad combinations, the markdown was being finicky with only one row, and I hoped that would fix it.

Comment: @JonasMetzler edited the table to remove the relationship table ID and the other examples.

Comment: @OperaFloozy It's unlucky you edit your question all time and change your requirements. My answer is based on your previous result where you had three columns and further users. I hope you can verify it anyway. Please check if it helps.

Comment: @JonasMetzler My apologies. I was requested (by you and others) to provide more information for clarity and therefore did so. The requirements and initial question have not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to do something like this:

```
WITH user_items AS
  (SELECT 
    username,
    LISTAGG(item,',') AS item_list
  FROM attributes
  GROUP BY username)
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER(ORDER BY u.username) AS Bad_Combo_User_ID,
  u.username, 
  c.ComboID
FROM user_items u
INNER JOIN combinations c ON
  INSTR(u.item_list, c.item1) > 0
  AND INSTR(u.item_list, c.item2) > 0;
```

I created a [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VOJxxsUt) based on your sample data, extended with some data for user D4 and E5.

The result seems correct to me and meets your requirements.

How does this query work?

First, we use a `CTE` to build a comma-separated list of all items that appear per user in the attributes table.

Then we use the main query to compare the list of items with the items in the combinations table. In the `ON` clause of the `INNER JOIN` we say that both items from the combination table in the same row must appear in the "item list" of the user. If that's the case, we add this user to the result.

So the result will show those users only that have an invalid combination of items. The `ROW_NUMBER` just creates an increasing number sorted by the username. As I read your question, that's what you want to do.

Even in case I understood something wrong and the answer is not 100% what you wanted to do, I think this should be a sufficient help to point you to the right direction. Please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have fixed set of combined attributes, you may use an approach similar to this question: [SQL query: Simulating an "AND" over several rows instead of sub-querying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163887/sql-query-simulating-an-and-over-several-rows-instead-of-sub-querying).

Transform columns to rows with `unpivot` to represent items as list and do `left join` to find matched items. Constant 2 at the very end is a number of items in combination (i.e. number of columns in source table for your case).

```
with combos_unpivot as (
  select *
  from combos
  unpivot (
    item for num in (item1 as 1, item2 as 2)
  )
)

select
  u.user_,
  c.comboid
from users u
  left join combos_unpivot c
    on u.item = c.item
group by u.user_, c.comboid
having count(c.item) = 2
```

For your sample data

```
create table combos(ComboID, Item1, Item2) as
  select 1, 'Ice Cream', 'Hot Sauce' from dual union all
  select 2, 'Asparagus', 'Chocolate' from dual union all
  select 3, 'Peanut Butter', 'Steak' from dual union all
  select 4, 'Asparagus', 'Ice Cream' from dual
```

```
create table users (UserAttributeID, User_, Item) as
  select 1, 'A1', 'Ice Cream' from dual union all
  select 2, 'B2', 'Asparagus' from dual union all
  select 3, 'A1', 'Chocolate' from dual union all
  select 4, 'B2', 'Ice Cream' from dual union all
  select 5, 'C3', 'Steak' from dual union all
  select 6, 'C3', 'Ice Cream' from dual union all
  select 7, 'C3', 'Chocolate' from dual
```

it returns

| USER_ | COMBOID |
| --- | --- |
| B2 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GDg15wU0)

Note that it scales quite well because there's an equijoin with no functions that most probably will result in hash join.

If you want to scale this for unlimited combo size and store combo items as rows instead of columns, then it is also easy to adapt: count combo size in the CTE and use that combo size inside `having` instead of constant.

```
with combos_unpivot as (
  select ComboID, Item, count(*) over(partition by ComboID) as combo_size
  from combos_vertical
)

select
  u.user_,
  c.comboid
from users u
  left join combos_unpivot c
    on u.item = c.item
group by u.user_, c.comboid
having count(c.item) = max(c.combo_size)
```

For this added sample data:

```
create table combos_vertical(ComboID, itemno, Item) as
  select 1, 1, 'Ice Cream'  from dual union all
  select 1, 1, 'Hot Sauce' from dual union all
  select 2, 1, 'Asparagus' from dual union all
  select 2, 2, 'Chocolate' from dual union all
  select 3, 1, 'Peanut Butter' from dual union all
  select 3, 2, 'Steak' from dual union all
  select 4, 1, 'Asparagus' from dual union all
  select 4, 2, 'Ice Cream' from dual union all
  select 5, 1, 'Steak' from dual union all
  select 5, 2, 'Ice Cream' from dual union all
  select 5, 3, 'Chocolate' from dual
```

it will return

| USER_ | COMBOID |
| --- | --- |
| B2 | 4 |
| C3 | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/p3va9iw5)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple sql where HAVING clause defines if there is a combination per user from both columns ITEM_1 and ITEM_2 - which is a bad combo.

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
Select      a.USER_ID, c.ID "BAD_COMBO_ID"
From        combos c
Left Join   attribs a ON(   a.ITEM IN( c.ITEM_1, c.ITEM_2 ) )
Group By  a.USER_ID, c.ID
Having    Count(Distinct  Case  When a.ITEM = c.ITEM_1 Then 1
                                When a.ITEM = c.ITEM_2 Then 2
                          End) > 1
```

... which with sample data provided ...

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    combos (ID, ITEM_1, ITEM_2) AS
        (   Select 1, 'Ice Cream', 'Hot Sauce' From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'Asparagus', 'Chocolate' From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'Peanut Butter', 'Steak' From Dual Union All
            Select 4, 'Asparagus', 'Ice Cream' From Dual 
        ), 
    attribs (ID, USER_ID, ITEM) AS
        (   Select 1, 'A1', 'Ice Cream' From Dual Union All 
            Select 2, 'B2', 'Asparagus' From Dual Union All 
            Select 3, 'A1', 'Chocolate' From Dual Union All 
            Select 4, 'B2', 'Ice Cream' From Dual Union All 
            Select 5, 'C3', 'Steak' From Dual Union All 
            Select 6, 'C3', 'Ice Cream' From Dual Union All 
            Select 7, 'C3', 'Chocolate' From Dual 
    )
```

... results with :

```sql
--      R e s u l t :
--  USER_ID BAD_COMBO_ID
--  ------- ------------
--  B2            4
```

Additionaly, if you need to see the combo just add c.ITEM_1 || '-' || c.ITEM_2 "COMBO" to selection list and c.ITEM_1, c.ITEM_2 to Group By clause. The result should be:

```sql
--      R e s u l t :
--  USER_ID BAD_COMBO_ID COMBO
--  ------- ------------ ---------------------------
--  B2            4      Asparagus-Ice Cream
```